# Problemas con función num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

Actualmente tengo un problema con la función `num_rows` para obtener información si existe ya un registro con los datos que estoy solicitando, si me pueden ayudar con el error mucho se lo sabría agradecer

```
 $consultaIdRepresentante = "select id_representante, cedulaRepresentante from representantes
where cedulaRepresentante = '$_POST[cedulaRepresentante]'";

$consultarRepresentante = mysqli_query($conexion,$consultaIdRepresentante) or die 
("Problemas en consulta representante insertar".mysqli_error($conexion));

$resultadoConsultaRepresentante = mysqli_num_rows($consultarRepresentante) or die 
("Problemas obtener numero de registro representante".mysqli_error($conexion));
if ($resultadoConsultaRepresentante == 1) {
    echo "funciona";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La consulta, ejecutada directamente sobre la base de datos, devuelve datos?

Comment: Parece que te esta devolviendo cero (`0`) por eso se ejecuta el `die()`;

Comment: Ayer le elimine el die y me funcionó, posiblemente sería eso.

Answer (score 0):

> Si la función `mysqli_num_rows` devolviera cero (*no se encontraron concidendias*) provocaría que se ejecute el `die()`.

Posible solución:

```
$resultadoConsultaRepresentante = mysqli_num_rows($consultarRepresentante);
if ($resultadoConsultaRepresentante == 1) {
    echo "funciona";
} else if ($resultadoConsultaRepresentante == 0) {
    die("La cedula '$_POST[cedulaRepresentante]' no existe.");
} else {
   echo "Se encontraron $resultadoConsultaRepresentante resultados".
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que ejecute `die()` y evitarte otra consulta bastaria con

```
if ($consultarRepresentante = mysqli_query($conexion, $consultaIdRepresentante)) {
    $rows = $consultarRepresentante->num_rows;
    if ($rows == 0) {
        die("No hay registros");
    } else {
        //Si existe
    }
}else{
    die("Problemas en consulta representante insertar".mysqli_error($conexion));
}
```